# What does "reel in" mean in "Together with the fishing industry, tourism reels in about $6 billion annually"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I found this sentence while reading [Great Barrier Reef](http://www.wwf.org.au/what-we-do/oceans/great-barrier-reef).

> Together with the fishing industry, tourism reels in about $6 billion annually and supports some 69,000 Australian jobs.

Would anyone guide me reel in meaning in this sentence? I tried Cambridge which have different phrasal verbs for reel in. I also tried Macmillan dictionary. I understand it giving the sense of overall or pull overall. Although this is not exactly mention in dictionaries. Here are the entries

> 1. [reel in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reel-sb-sth-in?fallbackFrom=british-grammar&q=reel+in) (Cambridge)
>      to get control of something or someone, sometimes by offering something in exchange: *The article offers tips on how computer users can avoid being reeled in by internet scams.*
> 2. [reel in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/reel-in) (Macmillan)
>      to bring a fish toward you by turning the reel of a fishing rod

Please suggest the meaning of reels in related to context in aforementioned sentence.

Comment: Which online dictionaries have you tried?

Comment: I tried cambridge which have different phrasal verbs for reel in. I also tried macmillan dictionary. I understand it giving the sense of overall or pull overall. Although this is not exactly mention in dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for adding meaning from dictionaries. However you looking cambridge online you will find different versions of reel in that creating the confusion as well.

Answer (score 3):

When talking about fishing, a *reel* refers to a *fishing reel*.
[image]

> A [fishing reel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_reel) is a cylindrical device attached to a fishing rod used in winding and stowing line.

You use a reel to draw the fishing line to recover a fish you have caught. The use of *reel in* in the example is a play on words. It's being used figuratively to mean that tourism and the fishing industry together **bring in** (generate) about $6 billion annually. Notice that tourism isn't *actually* pulling a line.

Comment: Nothing fishy about your excellent answer!

Comment: I think the exact phrasal verb is 'reel in' not just reel. Also it's not talking about fishing reel.